# SharePoint - How do I limit the number of versions per document in a document library?

Tags: sharepoint

How do I limit the number of versions per document in a document library? We'd like to do this to save space, as SharePoint stores a full copy of each version of a document in a library (so I've been told).
 Also, once implemented, what happens to the old versions beyond the threshold? For instance, if I have a file with 30 versions, and I implement a 10 version limit, do the oldest 20 versions get deleted?

Thanks!

KA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could write an [Event Handler](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/03/sample-event-handler-to-set-permissions.html) and attach it to your document library; when document versions count reach your custom limit, it's up to you decide what to do with previous versions.

**EDIT:** Sorry, there are a simpler way: go to your document library definition; below "General Settings", select "Versioning settings" and enter your version count limits in "Optionally limit the number of versions to retain".

Comment: Hey Rubens, 

 Thanks for the answer! Isn't there a way to do it with a configuration change at the top-level or site-level administration settings?